# CDO.Message Classic ASP - Adding attachment

Tags: asp-classic, cdo.message

I am having problems trying to add an attachment to an email using Classic ASP. I have trawled forums and it seems I needed to add .AddAttachment = "c:\users\samplb\logoblack.gif" but the form doesn't work anymore. It comes up with the "The website cannot display the page" message.

Here is my Code:

```
<% 

name = request.form("name")
Message = request.form("Message")


Set cdoConfig = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")  

With cdoConfig.Fields  
    .Item(cdoSendUsingMethod) = cdoSendUsingPort  
    .Item(cdoSMTPServer) = "xxx"  
    .Update  
End With 

Set cdoMessage = CreateObject("CDO.Message")  

With cdoMessage 
    Set .Configuration = cdoConfig 
    .From = "test@me.co.uk"
    .To = "test@me.co.uk" 
    .Subject = "Feedback / Suggestions" 
    .AddAttachment = "c:\users\samplb\logoblack.gif" 
    .TextBody = "Name: " & name & vbcrlf & vbcrlf & "Message: " & Message  
    .Send 
End With 

Set cdoMessage = Nothing  
Set cdoConfig = Nothing  
%>
```

Does anyone know why it might not be working? When I take the .AddAttachment out the form works fine but I really need it to send the attachment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is `.AddAttachment()` is a method not a property try changing your code like this;

```vb
Call .AddAttachment("c:\users\samplb\logoblack.gif")
```

or to return the attachment as a `CDO.BodyPart` use;

```vb
Set cdoBodyPart = .AddAttachment("c:\users\samplb\logoblack.gif")
```

> **Note:** *See the [AddAttachment Method (MSDN Library)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms526983%28v=exchg.10%29.aspx) for more information about the method and how to use it.*